# Uncaught Error: Couldn't find Materialize object on window

Tags: javascript, angular, materialize, angular2-materialize

I'm trying to use `MaterializeCSS` on my `Angular 6` app. I'm using `materialize-css` and `angular2-materialize` module from `npm`. When I run the app it builds successfully. But I've got this error in the browser console. And the app doesn't show on the browser.

> Uncaught Error: Couldn't find Materialize object on window. It is
>   created by the materialize-css library. Please import materialize-css
>   before importing angular2-materialize.

Though I imported them in the ***app.module.ts***

Here is my code:

***app.module.ts***

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import 'materialize-css';
import { MaterializeModule } from 'angular2-materialize';

import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';
import { SliderComponent } from './layout/slider/slider.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LayoutComponent,
    SliderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MaterializeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

styles and scripts array from **angular.json**

```
"styles": [
    "./node_modules/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss",
    "src/styles.sass"
],
"scripts": [
    "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"
]
```

I'm not using `jQuery` since `jQuery` is no longer a dependency of `materialize-css` and I don't want to mix up `jQuery` and `Angular`

I've also opened an issue on Github about this. Check it [here](https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize/issues/440).

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes. Basically `materialize-css`  have changed their object name from `Materialize` to `M` in `v1.0.0`. But `angular2-materialize` have built on top of `v0.100.2`. That's why this error has been generated. You can change the object name by editing the source code of `angular2-materialize` from `node_modules` folder. But that needs a ton of effort. So I have decided to drop `angular2-materialize` module and just use `materialize-css` `v1.0.0`. And for this only `materialize-css` library is required. You don't need any other dependencies like `jQuery` or `HammerJS`. @danwellman

Comment: Ok great, thanks for the info :)